# Ember use getOwner to access config in acceptance tests

Tags: ember.js

While in integration tests I can use:

```
import getOwner from 'ember-owner/get';
```

and then

```
moduleForComponent('mycomponent', 'Integration | Component | mycomponent', {
    integration: true,
    beforeEach() {
        const config = getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment');
```

In acceptance test `getOwner(this)` is undefined and the only option I have to do this without getOwner is:

```
moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | cool test', {
    beforeEach() {
        const config = this.application.__container__.lookupFactory('config:environment');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need getOwner to get your config, you simply import it in your file `import config from 'yourAppName/config/environment';`

Comment: @PatsyIssa that's a static import. What about the runtime config?

Comment: @PatsyIssa is correct, you will get exactly the same object via the import that you would get from resolveRegistration('config:environment').